# CakePHP 2.0 magic find functions with unconventional table column names

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

So, I would like to use this magic find function in my CakePHP 2.0 app:

```
$profile = $this->Profile->findByUserId($user['User']['id']);
```

However, the field in question is called `userId`, not `user_id`.  The code above throws an error - column `user_id` is missing.

Is there a way to force Cake to try to look for camel cased column names?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to override the appropriate function for that. Cake's conventions are just that, conventions. If you stray from them, you'll need to put in more manual work. So either create the function `findByUserId` in the appropriate model, or override the magic `__call` function.